# how to do group validation for address fields in rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails-4

I want to code this logic in the model file:

if :addr_streetno is entered, then ensure that :addr_state, :addr_city and :addr_zip are also entered.

Right now, what I have is this but I can get by without entering zipcode easily:

```
[:addr_aptno, :addr_zip].each do |n|
    validates n, numericality: { only_integer: true, 
                                :greater_than => 0,
                                :allow_blank => true
                               }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the `if` option for `validates`:

```
validates :addr_state, presence: true, if: :addr_streetno
validates :addr_city, presence: true, if: :addr_streetno
validates :addr_zip, presence: true, if: :addr_streetno
validates :addr_aptno, numericality: { only_integer: true, greater_than: 0 }, allow_blank: true
validates :addr_zip, numericality: { only_integer: true, greater_than: 0 }, allow_blank: true
```